# Different way of adding tabs in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-tabhost

I am trying to make 3-Tabs in a activity.

With my research I decided I am using fragments for this.

As I know per my knowledge we can make tabs in three ways

1. Using Fragmented tabhost
2. Using SherlockLibrary
3. Using ActionBar Tabs
4. Making my own tabs using fragments by placing three buttons on
   activity and making dynamic transistion between the fragment screens

I am trying to follow 4th option.

**My Question**:
Will this have any disadvantage compared to first three methods?

Comment: There's another method: `TabHost` + `TabWidget`

Comment: If you want to implement your own sort of 'tab' interface using buttons and a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, that would be a totally valid option. This gives you more control over the tabs, with a bit more overhead work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As i know per my knowledge we can make tabs in three ways

- "Using SherlockLibrary" and "Using ActionBar Tabs" are the same thing, with the only difference being whether you are using ActionBarSherlock as an action bar backport or not
- As NKN pointed out, you missed `TabHost`, `TabWidget`, and views for your tabs
- You also missed what's probably the most popular option today, which is `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator (`PagerTabStrip`, `TabPageIndicator` from the ViewPagerIndicator library, etc.).

> Will this have any disadvantage compared to first three methods?

It will not meet user expectations for the look and feel of tabs, without a lot of redundant work on the design. It would seem simpler to use any of the other solutions.